# How to convert X and Y screen coordinates to -1.0, 1.0 float? (in C)

Tags: c, math, floating-point, screen, coordinates

I'm trying to convert X and Y screen coordinates to a float range of -1.0, to 1.0.

(-1,-1 being 0,0 and if the resolution was 640x480, 1,1 would be 640,480. 0,0 would be 320,240... the center.)

How would I approach this? I made several futile attempts, and I'm not exactly mathematically inclined.

Comment: How about 
outx = (X-320)/640;
outy = (Y-240)/480;

Comment: @Cobusve Or `outx = (X-320)/640.0f;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some C code

```
void convert(int X, int Y)
{
  float newx = 2*(X-320.0f)/640.0f;
  float newy = 2*(Y-240.0f)/480.0f;

  printf("New x = %f, New y = %f", newx, newy);
}
```

EDIT: Added the f suffix to ensure we do not do integer math !

Comment: `f` is not a valid integer constant suffix. Write `320.f` or `320.0f`.

Comment: Really ? C99 paragraph 6.4.4.2 seems to disagree with you. I quote : "An unsuffixed floating constant has type double. If suffixed by the letter f or F, it has type float. If suffixed by the letter l or L, it has type long double." and that also compiles ...

Comment: Yes. Look up the differences between a floating vs. integer constant. What compiler did you use?

Comment: I was using our compiler XC8. Ok, also checked with gcc and that does complain. I am not sure how to interpret the standard on that one ... I see "A floating constant has a significand part that may be followed by an exponent part and a suffix that specifies its type. The components of the significand part may include a digit sequence representing the whole-number part, followed by a period (.), followed by a digit sequence representing the fraction part. " None of that requires the ".", it has "may" everywhere ?

Comment: The syntax is easier to understand: `floating-constant` -> `decimal-floating-constant` -> `fractional-constant` (`.` is not `opt`). So either it's a bug or at least a weird extension as a `f`/`F` integer constant suffix seems confusing. What's the type of `320L`? `long` or `long double`? (Btw. your answer is correct now, so +1.)

Comment: I looked at the spec and I agree with you. The . is not opt, so the edit I made is necessary. Thanks for pointing it out !

Answer (score 0):

In the X direction:

1. Screen coordinate `0` corresponds to `-1.0`.
2. Screen coordinate `640` corresponds to `1.0`.

You can convert that to an equation:

Given `fX` in floating point coordinates, the screen coordinate `sX` is:

```
sX = 640*(fX + 1.0)/2.0
```

or

```
sX = 320*(fX + 1.0)
```

Similarly, given `fY` in floating point coordinates, the screen coordinate `sY` is:

```
sY = 480*(fY + 1.0)/2.0
```

or

```
sY = 240*(fY + 1.0)
```

The inverse of that:

Given `sX` in screen coordinates, `fX` in real coordinates is:

```
fX = (sX/320 - 1.0)
```

Given `sY` in screen coordinates, `fY` in real coordinates is:

```
fY = (sY/240 - 1.0)
```

When you convert that to code, make sure the last two equations have a `1.0`. Otherwise, you'll lose accuracy due to integer division.

```
fX = (1.0*sX/320 - 1.0)
fY = (1.0*sY/240 - 1.0)
```

Comment: When I looked there was only one ;)

Comment: @Cobusve, I started with the equations that convert from fX and fY to sX and sY. Then, I added the other two equations.

Comment: I noticed. I removed my down-vote for you. If you started with what OP actually asked that would not have happened :). When I commented the answer contained no equation which solved the problem. You really should  finish your answers before posting ...